# How to Serve Django Application With Apache2 and Mod WSGI

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I want to serve my Django applications using `Apache2` and the `mod_wsgi` module. I have setup an Apache virtualhost at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`and I have made some configuration changes to WSGI at `home/username/development/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py` However, when I navigate to mydomain.com, I am being presented with the 500 Internal Server Error: `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`. I am very new to server development and have never used Apache2 before so I am unsure as to where I have gone wrong in my configuration. Below you will find my virtualhost configuration file as well as my `WSGI` file. Additionally, I have provided the structure layout of my project directory in case this helps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

directory structure

```
>> home
    >> username
        >> development
            >> mysite
                >> mysite
                    >> settings.py
                    >> wsgi.py
                >> website
                    >> static
                >> manage.py
            >> venv
```

mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot /home/username/development/mysite
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/development/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

 WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5
 WSGIProcessGroup mydomain.com

 <directory /home/username/development/mysite>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /home/username/development/mysite/website/static/

 <Directory /home/username/development/mysite/website/static>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/username/development/mysite')
# adjust the Python version in the line below as needed
sys.path.append('/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

try:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
except Exception:
    # Error loading applications
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
        traceback.print_exc()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

error.log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_connect in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Aug 05 06:25:02.417656 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 11931] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Mon Aug 05 06:25:02.417679 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 11931] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Mon Aug 05 06:25:02.418568 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11931] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 05 06:25:02.418590 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11931] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.950527 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0] mod_wsgi (pid=23705): Target WSGI script '/home/username/development/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.950606 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0] mod_wsgi (pid=23705): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/username/development/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951482 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951546 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951552 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951564 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951569 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951577 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951597 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951607 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951612 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951619 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951623 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951630 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951634 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951640 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "/home/username/development/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951644 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951651 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951657 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951664 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951671 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951678 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951696 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951704 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Aug 05 10:09:39.951725 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 23705] [remote 10.100.60.43:0] ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
[Mon Aug 05 10:52:33.048933 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11931] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

mysite.conf edit

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot /home/username/development/mysite
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/development/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

 WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain.com  python-home=/home/username/development/venv python-path=/home/username/developement/mysite
 WSGIProcessGroup mydomain.com

 <directory /home/username/development/mysite>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /home/username/development/mysite/website/static/

 <Directory /home/username/development/mysite/website/static>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And what does the Apache error log show?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the error logs

Comment: Not supplying location of virtual environment correctly. See https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html And not telling mod_wsgi where your Django project parent directory is so it can import your project. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ Also shouldn't use that `kill()` code in `wsgi.py`. See the `startup-timeout` option for daemon mode instead https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I made some changes according to the documentation, and now I am getting `Bad Request (400)`. Please see my edit. I am using `mod_wsgi` daemon mode and I double checked the `virtualenvironment` path to be correct.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton nevermind, it is working now, thank you!